# 403 error with no reason

Tags: errors, installation

I'm recently trying to install wordpress ( which i did many many times with no problem ) on shared hosting.

I have changed the wp_config.php file with the required info and uploaded wordpress into a directory.

I have even changed the CHMOD permission of all the files in the wordpress directory to 777, I know it's not a wise thing to do, but just to see where the problem is, but even then it didn't work. The same problem persists (error 403 forbidden).

I'm using the latest version of wordpress 4.4.1 .

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 0):

403 forbidden means that your browser isn't able to load the scripts up because your server isn't allowing it. This is a hard one to solve because anything could be blocking the server: 
- Most likely this is a server permissions/ownership issue, so ask your host what's going on 
- check your .htaccess files for anything strange. 
- try a full [Manual Upgrade](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update), to make sure all the WordPress files are there and correct.. 
- Make sure to backup everything (including database) before doing any action, in case.